# offline web page caching with persistent data

Tags: android, html, caching, progressive-web-apps, browser-cache

Hi i'm trying to make my HTML webpage offline for android and IOS devices. My problem is that I need to store a lot of data. This data (css,js,images,html) needs to be persistent. (even after shutdown of the device)

USE: Someone types the URL and gets the whole page offline available.

What is the best way to persist your data? and is it possible without making a hybrid or native app, just with caching and maybe appcache/indexeddb.

EDIT: i have found that indexed db in combination with dexies my best guess is for a solution. are there any do's or don'ts, alternatives or tutorials you guys suggest ?

Comment: Please add your sample code, to describe your problem, that would help.

Comment: hey thank you for the response, i do not have a specific code because i do not know what type of chaching/storage i should use. This is more of a general question on how to store persistent data from android browser with just caching and no native or hybrid app. i was hoping that someone had some knowledge on html persistent caching.

Comment: This should give you some info you need for your research. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa

Comment: thank you very much, this article helps alot. I'm going to start testing now with chache API and Indexeddb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on the application personality I sometimes render the entire site/application in the service worker when the service worker is installed/activated.
I wrote about an example app I did last October for a conference, https://love2dev.com/pwa/pubcon/

As far as strategy, I vary things. For data (think JSON) I tend to cache in IndexedDB (I like localforage b/c it is simple).
For site assets (HTML, JS, CSS, Fonts and often media) I use service worker cache.
If a site is heavy on media, I persist images and video in IDB b/c iOS limits service worker cache to 50MB. 50MB should be more than enough for any web application core assets as they should really be measured in kb, not MB anyway.
iOS gives you several GB of IDB storage, depending on how much disk space is available on the device.
I have built multiple SAAS apps using this strategy and never hit data quotas. Of course lots of video or images will of course consume more space and you need to watch for quota exceeded errors.

Users will also be prompted to give permission for extended storage as well, so be aware of that barrier as you may need to educate the user about this.

Comment: thank you very much this post is also very helpfull! I will try using that strategy and structure for saving my data,cache,etc. it seems that for the moment i won't hit any cache limits.  read the article and it's a good example of what my app should provide! is there any more detailed info about this pubcon app?